# assembly MOV instruction operands

Tags: assembly

when we want to make an initialized variable like this:

```
name db 'zara ali'
```

we have made a byte size variable but we stored a string in it

how it is possible??

and when we use this instruction:

```
MOV ecx, name
```

we have stored a byte sized variable in a 4 byte size register, while in MOV instruction both operands must be of same size.
how it's possible??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`name db 'zara ali'` is just a shorthand for

```
name db 'z', 'a', 'r', 'a', ' ', 'a','l','i'
```

that is another shorthand for

```
name db 'z'
     db 'a'
     db 'r'
     db 'a'
     db ' '
     db 'a'
     db 'l'
     db 'i'
```

thus that's a sequence of bytes, the address of the first one is given the name `name`.

`MOV ecx, name` has different semantics in different assemblers.
In NASM it doesn't read the variable `name` it stores the value of the symbol `name` in `ecx` - it is equivalent to the TASM/MASM notation

```
mov ecx, OFFSET name
lea ecx, name           ;This is an abuse of notation but valid in TASM
```

In MASM/TASM it reads the DWORD (implied by the use of a DWORD register like `ecx`) at the address `name`, thus reading the first four bytes (`zara`).
It is equivalent of `mov ecx, [name]` or `mov ecx, DWORD [name]` in NASM.

Comment: To be a smart ass...embly expert: "name" is just a label, not a variable. Actually, assemblers shoulfn't check for a size or a length of the following data.  Maybe it's clearer for newbies to translate "db" to "data bytes".

Comment: @rkhb I agree! But still, I'm unsure how you are suggesting I should improve my answer :)

Comment: No no, your answer is good and clear. That were just my 2 cents. :-)